# Bootstrap Carousel Image Loading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

The bootstrap carousel is working and looping around images. However, when you first open the web page, the carousel slider displays a empty background for a split-second. Afterwards, it is working properly.

I tried to solve it through this css but does not work.

```
.carousel-control {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

There are some questions related to preload whole carousel. What kind of jquery code is needed to do that?

Do you know how to get rid of the split-second empty background?

```
  <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">

      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="{% static 'img/img1.jpg' %}" alt="First slide" />
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="{% static 'img/img2.jpg' %}" alt="Second slide">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img class="third-slide" src="{% static 'img/img3.jpg' %}" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey @coder, how about some code?

Comment: Thank you. Code is simple and pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

CSS:

```
.preload{ display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="preload">
<img src="img/img1.jpg" />
<img src="img/img2.jpg" />
<img src="img/img3.jpg" />
</div>
```